# How to have a dynamic link for a video?

Tags: php, javascript, html, asp.net

Hi I am currently observing a few sites for potential ideas. One thing I came across on one of the sites is how the source url of a video includes the timestamp in it. So for example, if I click on the link to view the video, the time that the server acknowledges the request is put into the actual video url (this can be seen when looking at the source code) - eg `nameOfVideo_17062013_192145.mp4`. Also this link is only valid for a short time before a new request and a new link is required. My question is, obviously the video only has one real source, but how is the website able to cover up the real source by one with a timestamp (which shouldnt be the real source as the time will always change and the location wont always change). This is assuming  there is a cover up. Secondly, is it possible to find out the true location of a video? Unfortunatley I dont want to give links to these websites and discuss them here without the owners permission. As a programmer, I am interested in how this concept works. Thanks

Comment: Can you try modifying the timestamp part of the URL and see if it gets you the same video?

Comment: @user1152309 I tried that and it gives an error because the link does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how is the website able to cover up the real source by one with a timestamp

HTTP URLs are mapped on to resources by software. The resources could be files on the file system, or they could be generated on the fly.  The mapping could be done by the HTTP server itself or it could be a program called by the HTTP server. There are many options for both.

An Apache configuration **might** look something like:

```
FastCgiServer  /opt/bin/video_fastcgi.pl -processes 3 -initial-env VIDEO_CONFIG=/opt/etc/video/production
Alias /videos/ /opt/bin/video_fastcgi.pl/
```

> Secondly, is it possible to find out the true location of a video?

The true location is a file on a disk somewhere. To access it you either need to be using the computer that is running the HTTP server or you need something to make it available over the network. There is no reason to assume that the HTTP server will make it available other than through the dynamic URL (and no way to find out what other URLs it is available at given a single example).

Comment: The videos on the site are user uploaded so will they still got stored on the computer?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins — "a disk somewhere" is part of a computer.